What is the purpose of this audio transformer in the circuit?
I was tasked at work to build some boards, which take a 12 V input from a car audio amplifier and output a lower voltage signal for further processing in a soundcard.
Schematic:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
As I don't know much about audio electronics, I want to know what the purpose of the audio transformer exactly is. I know that R1 & R2 act as a voltage divider to go from the 12 V output of the audio amplifier to 2 V, which should be the input level of the Line In port of the soundcard.
I also read that the audio transformer just acts as a galvanic isolation and to reduce noise, but I'm not sure.

Q1: What is the main purpose of this audio transformer in this circuit?

Q2: Why exactly do we need R3, and why is its value like this?
My end goal is to perhaps build this circuit on a PCB. Right now I'm building it on a prototype board with this audio transformer.

Q3: If I replace this audio transformer with a cheaper one, what do I need to keep in mind? Is the impedance relevant for this purpose?


Feel free to ask for further details.
Kind regards.

Audio transformers, 1:1, are usually 600 Ohm if my memory hasn't failed. They are crafted especially to support a wide audio range and are not exactly the same as some other 1:1 designs. The word "audio" in their marketing is important. I forget the details i read 30 years ago. So someone else may correct me or else explain the comprises involved.

This only answers Q1.
There are a couple of possible reasons for the transformer.

It eliminates ground loops which can cause interference due to current running through the car's chassis, etc., and causing small voltage drops which are added to the audio signal, producing noise.
Many car audio systems use bridge-mode amplifiers in a push-pull configuration so that the voltage to the speaker is doubled (and the power is quadrupled) to overcome the limitations of the 12 V supply. In this case neither terminal of the speaker is connected to audio ground.


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. Bridge mode amplifier driving soundcard via transformer isolation. (Divider resistors not shown.)
Note that the circuit will work with a regular amplifier and speaker with one terminal grounded.


What is the main purpose of this audio transformer in this circuit?

To provide galvanic isolation between earth/ground on the left side amplifier and earth/ground on the soundcard. This means it will work fine no matter which way round you connect the two wires to the amplifier and ditto for the soundcard. Call it a means of ensuring it is idiot-proof.
You might also know that many audio outputs feed a bridge tied load and you must use an isolation transformer/device rather than simple wires to connect to the sound card.

Why exactly do we need R3 and why is its value like this?

Well, you might not need it if the attenuation is sufficient from R1 and R2. After all, it's a 1:1 transformer and R3 can be moved to the driven side without much sweat or worry.

If I replace this audio transformer with a cheaper one, what do I need
to keep in mind? Is the impedance relevant for this purpose?

Stick with around 600 ohm for the audio transformer but, you can change the primary to secondary turns ratio from 1:1 down to something that is lower on the secondary side such as 2:1 or 5:1. The transformer you linked is 200 ohm 1:1 and this should be fine. If the turns ratio is 2:1 the secondary impedance will look like 40 ohm.
If you keep lowering the step-down ratio you'll reach a point when the signal into the line card isn't sufficient maybe but, you can always adjust R1 and R2 to restore a little amplification.
Make sure you don't feed to much voltage onto the transformer primary. I see that the one you linked has a voltage rating of around 2 volts RMS. This is probably also the reason why R1 and R2 are used.


Main purpose is to act as isolation between a bridge-driven output intended for driving a speaker, but actually passing the isolated signal safely to your sound card. It really does no significant noise reduction per se.

Who knows - everything in the circuit is unknown, including component parameters, audio output parameters, and input parameters. Therefore any resistor values and their existence in circuit are unknown. They may provide proper impedance matching and loading to have adequate bandwidth or flatness of the bandpass.

The problem is not replacing the old transformer with an equivalent, the problem is what you need from the new transformer to make it pass the signal you want best. A cheaper and different transformer may be better if it simply is more suitable for the thing you want to achieve, which we don't know.


